# Corda Could not create the DataSource: Validation Failed

Tags: corda

I've migrated from 4.0 to 4.3, I am getting validation issues on the data source. Anyone seen that before? I assume it is a liquibase issue where the hash is different for the change.

```
notary_1                      | [ERROR] 20:52:25+0000 [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Could not create the DataSource: Validation Failed:
notary_1                      |      1 change sets check sum
notary_1                      |           migration/node-services.changelog-init.xml::add-new-persistence-table::R3.Corda was: 8:cb3302a80bf346270e0d8f3509c64a9b but is now: 8:d1dd927506a41884e2d451b3d4e3c6b0
notary_1                      | : Could not create the DataSource: Validation Failed:
notary_1                      |      1 change sets check sum
notary_1                      |           migration/node-services.changelog-init.xml::add-new-persistence-table::R3.Corda was: 8:cb3302a80bf346270e0d8f3509c64a9b but is now: 8:d1dd927506a41884e2d451b3d4e3c6b0
notary_1                      |  [errorCode=1sgw0t1, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.3-RC01/1sgw0t1]
```

Comment: Which database? You might need to have a newer JDBC driver for some database.

Comment: I am just using the h2 embedded one but will double check. Thank you.

Comment: Hi is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds this in the future, it looks like 1174 solved his issue by upgrading the version of docker he was using.

Link to the github issue here: https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/6016